# Convert a 16 variable dictionary to dataframe

Tags: dataframe, dictionary

Hi I have a dictionary output like this that I would like to be converted into a dataframe.

```
{'data': [{'direction_color': 'greenFont',
   'rowDate': 'Apr 18, 2023',
   'rowDateRaw': 1681776000,
   'rowDateTimestamp': '2023-04-18T00:00:00Z',
   'last_close': '1,268.550',
   'last_open': '1,268.550',
   'last_max': '1,268.550',
   'last_min': '1,268.550',
   'volume': '',
   'volumeRaw': 0,
   'change_precent': '0.32',
   'last_closeRaw': '1268.55004882812500',
   'last_openRaw': '1268.55004882812500',
   'last_maxRaw': '1268.55004882812500',
   'last_minRaw': '1268.55004882812500',
   'change_precentRaw': 0.32187685232202745},
  {'direction_color': 'greenFont',
   'rowDate': 'Apr 17, 2023',
   'rowDateRaw': 1681689600,
   'rowDateTimestamp': '2023-04-17T00:00:00Z',
   'last_close': '1,264.480',
   'last_open': '1,264.480',
   'last_max': '1,264.480',
   'last_min': '1,264.480',
   'volume': '',
   'volumeRaw': 0,
   'change_precent': '1.03',
   'last_closeRaw': '1264.47998046875000',
   'last_openRaw': '1264.47998046875000',
   'last_maxRaw': '1264.47998046875000',
   'last_minRaw': '1264.47998046875000',
   'change_precentRaw': 1.0274672346024991}],
 'summary': {'last_highest': '1,268.550',
  'last_lowest': '1,264.480',
  'last_difference': '4.070',
  'last_avarage_total': '1,266.515',
  'last_change_percent': '1.353'}}
```

Dataframe will look like this.

[image]

Could you kindly help me please?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use Python reserved names (*like [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#func-dict)*) as your variable names but you're close :

```
use_cols = ["rowDateTimestamp", "last_close", "last_open",
            "last_max", "last_min", "volume", "volumeRaw"]
​
df = pd.DataFrame(obj["data"])[use_cols] # `obj` is to replace your `dict`
```

​Output :

```
print(df)

       rowDateTimestamp last_close  last_open   last_max   last_min volume  volumeRaw
0  2023-04-18T00:00:00Z  1,268.550  1,268.550  1,268.550  1,268.550                 0
1  2023-04-17T00:00:00Z  1,264.480  1,264.480  1,264.480  1,264.480                 0
```